# Creating a Youtube block using Views for Embedded media field module

Tags: 7, views, media, files

I created a content type called Videos.

In it there is a file field with a Embedded Media Field widget, and using the Media: YouTube module to post Youtube videos.

I created a block showing links to the latest 10 nodes of content type Videos.

This works fine.  However now I want to create another block showing a thumbnail of the latest video and if a user clicks on it, it will take the user to the node of that video.  I have played around in Views and there doesn't seem to be a way to expose the thumbnail of a video.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the formatter, that's how it works. You just change the Option of the field to Image Thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

In the new block view, add the video field and set it to display thumbnail in formatter. Then, select link to content to goto content page.
Apart from that to show latest videos, add sort criteria to post date in descending order